# How to design small web forms in html page

Tags: html, beautifulsoup

When i design our web-form then i see then my web-form is very small then my web page
Because my form have only two field (two  text-box two label) 
How i design it. then he look Beautiful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to learn about styles and Cascading Style Sheets (CSS). You can use this tutorial for example:

http://www.w3schools.com/css/

Answer (score 1):

Increase
- font size
- paddings
- textbox size

Reduce
- page size

Or add some nice pictures around... :P

Answer (score 1):

Bam! Chuck the following CSS into your CSS file. You may change the size of the font but generally all your form elements will now be nice and big.

```
input,button,select
{
    font-size:18px;
}
```

or, in your HTML

```
<style type="text/css">
    input,button,select
    {
        font-size:18px;
    }
</style>
```